# Pycharm: how to automatically restart Jupyter on project code change?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

In my Pycharm projects I use Jupyter to experiment and when something is mature enough I move it to Python files within the project, and make the notebook use it.
From time to time, while running a notebook I change that Python code but am forced to manually restart the server in order to make the notebook use the changed code.
I'd like Pycharm to automatically do it for me.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
Just added this two lines as a first cell in the notebook:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```